# jQuery star rating plugin

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [this jQuery star rating plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-API)

But where do you add the link that points to the PHP file where the data is inserted in the database?

Comment: Check out this new jQuery rating plugin with touch support, wide browser compatibility, and essentially radically better than all the other old ones. http://rateit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is what needs to be done:

```
$('input.wow').rating({
 callback: function(value){
            $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://www3.inrees.com/rating_films_ajax.php?action=voter",
data:"films_id=<?php echo $id; ?>&rating="+value,
        success: function(){
         alert(value);
                 }
              })

  }
})
```

Question answered and my middle finger to the conceiver of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Check that page source code: it seems there is no file do specify: it's a simple HTML form:

```
<form name="api-select">
    <span class="star-rating-control">
        <div class="rating-cancel"><a title="Cancel Rating"></a></div>
        <div class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live star-rating-on"><a title="A">A</a></div>
        <div class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live star-rating-on"><a title="B">B</a></div>
        <div class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live star-rating-on"><a title="C">C</a></div>
        <div class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live"><a title="D">D</a></div>
        <div class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live"><a title="E">E</a></div>
    </span>
    <input style="display: none;" class="star star-rating-applied" name="api-select-test" value="A" type="radio">
    <input style="display: none;" class="star star-rating-applied" name="api-select-test" value="B" type="radio">
    <input style="display: none;" class="star star-rating-applied" name="api-select-test" value="C" type="radio">
    <input style="display: none;" class="star star-rating-applied" name="api-select-test" value="D" type="radio">
    <input style="display: none;" class="star star-rating-applied" name="api-select-test" value="E" type="radio">
    <input value="Submit »" onclick="$(this).next().html( $(this.form).serialize() || '(nothing submitted)' );" type="button">
</form>
```

Therefore I think you should just set your `action` and `method` attributes on the form element.

Comment: so then I can use a function like this to submit using ajax? $("#stars").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://www3.inrees.com/rating_films_ajax.php?action=voter",
data:"films_id=<?php echo $id; ?>&rating="+$("#wow").val(),
        success: function(){

                 }
              })
         }  )

Comment: Just use the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to do an AJAX POST of the form, and you're done.

Comment: I used a simple ajax function and it does not work , how can someone build a plugin and not clearly explain this in the API?